# O parâmetro da minha função, quando 1, assume valor boolean e quando False assume valor Number. Como conserto isso? Dúvida em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, if, tipagem, booleano

Estou bem no início dos estudos com JS, então me perdi um pouco nesse exercício.

Preciso fazer a verificação de tipo do único parâmetro da função 'verifi'. Quando for True, retorna False e vice-versa, para booleans. Quando for um Number retorna a sua negação (Ex. 10, retonar -10).

Porém quando esse parâmetro é false, ele assume o valor de um Number, no caso o 0 (e retorna -0), quando ele é 1, assume o valor de um Boolean, no caso True (e retorna False).

Não entendo por que quando os parâmetros são 0 ou True, a função executa conforme esperado.

```js
function verifi(par){
    if (par == (true || false)){
        return !par
    } else if((par >= 0) || (par <= 0)){
        return par * (-1)
    } else{
        return "Não encontrado! O parâmetro é do tipo " + typeof par
    }
}

console.log(verifi(0)) //retorna -0, assim como esperado
console.log(verifi(1)) // deveria retornar -1, porém retorna false
console.log(verifi(false)) // deveria retornar true, porém retorna -0
console.log(verifi(true)) //retorna false, assim como esperado
```

Comment: Seu primeiro if parece ser o problema `(true || false)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando você faz

```js
if (par == (true || false))
```

você na realidade está fazendo

```js
if (par == true)
```

Ao fazer uma comparação utilizando `==` (comparação por igualdade), algumas conversões "indesejadas" são realizadas. Por exemplo, os seguintes exemplos imprimem `true`:

```js
console.log(1 == true);
console.log([1] == true);
console.log("1" == true);
```

O que você provavelmente queria ter feito era ter utilizado a comparação por identidade (`===`) e utilizar duas comparações distintas:

```
if (par === true || par === false)
```

ou

```
if (typeof par === "boolean")
```

Comment: Entendido, realmente me equivoquei nessas partes! Muito obrigado pela ajuda, funcionou perfeitamente agora.